# Add the extra element and value in Existing array

Tags: jquery

I have one array like this

> details:{ 0: {TruckAllocationId: 1, RefTaskId: 3, RefTruckId: 7,
>   TruckNo: "TH56445565", DriverName: "driver"} 1: {TruckAllocationId: 2,
>   RefTaskId: 3, RefTruckId: 9, TruckNo: "88989798990", DriverName:
>   "dasdah"} }

I have to add few more value in the above array

Example I want to add new element and value 0th and 1st array age is added in the below array

> 0: {TruckAllocationId: 1, RefTaskId: 3, RefTruckId: 7, TruckNo:
>   "TH56445565", DriverName: "driver",Age:16} 1: {TruckAllocationId: 2,
>   RefTaskId: 3, RefTruckId: 9, TruckNo: "88989798990", DriverName:
>   "dasdah",Age:18}

I try below code its not working

```
if (typeof rowA.details != 'undefined')
{
    for (var i = 0; i < rowA.details.length; i++) {
        rowA.details[i].push({
            WheeloadermapFlag: _JsonValue["Table"[counter].WheeloadermapFlag
                       , TruckAllocationStatus: _JsonValue["Table"][counter].TruckAllocationStatus
                       , NoofTruckRequired: _JsonValue["Table"][counter].NoofTruckRequired
                       , MappedTruck: _JsonValue["Table"][counter].MappedTruck
                       ,
        })
    }    
}
```

Help Me in Above Problem

Comment: It's an Object Literal not an array. Actually it's a child of another object? It has a colon instead of a equal `=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object named "details" is not the array - it's the object. If you like to keep it, just use property names as strings. Like `"0": {....}`.
And so then you should use objects properties to change/delete/add values to it.
Like `rowA.details[i].DriverName = "Name"` or `rowA.details[i]["DriverName"] = "Name"`.

If you don't want to keep "detail" the object, delete the properties and make it an actual array. Then your code will work. Like `details = [{}, {}, ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable contains an Object Literal not an array. You might need to convert it to an array first or loop over the object.

> **CONVERT TO ARRAY**

```js
var rowA = {
  'details': {
    '0': {'TruckAllocationId': 1, 'RefTaskId': 3, 'RefTruckId': 7, 'TruckNo': 'TH56445565', 'DriverName': 'driver'},
    '1': {'TruckAllocationId': 2, 'RefTaskId': 3, 'RefTruckId': 9, 'TruckNo': '88989798990', 'DriverName': 'dasdah'}
  }
};


if (typeof rowA.details != 'undefined') {
  rowA.details = Object.values(rowA.details);
  for (var i = 0; i < rowA.details.length; i++) {
    // Your action here
    rowA.details[i]['Age'] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 20;
    console.log(rowA.details[i]);
  }
}
```

> **LOOP OVER THE OBJECT**

```js
var rowA = {
  'details': {
    '0': {'TruckAllocationId': 1, 'RefTaskId': 3, 'RefTruckId': 7, 'TruckNo': 'TH56445565', 'DriverName': 'driver'},
    '1': {'TruckAllocationId': 2, 'RefTaskId': 3, 'RefTruckId': 9, 'TruckNo': '88989798990', 'DriverName': 'dasdah'}
  }
};


if (typeof rowA.details != 'undefined') {
  for (key in rowA.details) {
    // Your action here
    // key is the Key of the object
    // to pass anything to the current index use rowA.details[key]
    // Example : rowA.details[key] = 'Amazing'
    rowA.details[key]['Age'] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 20;
    console.log(key, rowA.details[key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `details` is an array so this is what you can do to achieve what you want.

```js
details = [
{TruckAllocationId: 1, RefTaskId: 3, RefTruckId: 7, TruckNo: "TH56445565", DriverName: "driver"},
{TruckAllocationId: 2, RefTaskId: 3, RefTruckId: 9, TruckNo: "88989798990", DriverName: "dasdah"}
]
details[0]['Age'] = 16
details[1]['Age'] = 18
console.log(details)
```

Comment: I need different between json,object,array